# Excluding posts from a category but only if they're not in multiple categories

Tags: categories, wp-query, terms

I am looking to exclude a category in Wordpress. I am referring to the Wordpress Codex page on `wp_query` but I am having the following problem:

1. I want to exclude posts from category 1,
2. but if a post is in category 1 and category 2 (or any other category
   other than 1), then I still want it to show.

So, I only want posts to be excluded if they're exclusively in category 1.

Comment: Please follow up on the questions you asked, it's an important part of the process on WPSE - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) for a deeper insight. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by getting an array of category ids you want to show. We can use [get_terms()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) for this:

```
$taxonomy = array(
    'category'
);
$args = array(
    'exclude' => array('111'),//id of the category term you want to exclude  
    'fields' => 'ids'
);
$ct_ids = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );
```

Now you can use this to create your secondary query with [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) by using the [Category Parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) `category__in` like this:

```
$args = array(
    'category__in' => $ct_ids
);
$scnd_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

If you for example want to do this just for your home page, than there is no need for a custom secondary query, you can achieve it by hooking into the [pre_get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action like this:

```
function show_all_but_category_xyz( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'category__in', $ct_ids );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'show_all_but_category_xyz' );
```